# Is there a way to view the "LATEST-1" version in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

Is there any way to reference the previous version of every file in a directory in clearcase in the config specs?

I have read through the documentation [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-6-2), however there is no mention of how to step back 'n' iterations. I am looking for something such as:

```
element Path/To/Directory/* /main/LATEST-1
```

...in that it will step back every file one iteration, instead of, for example, choosing a date/label to go to.

**-----UPDATE:-----**

I'm just adding this in case it's of use to others - it's not an answer as such but it's how I worked around it:

I was able to capture the previous version number from the response to submitting:

```
ct descr Path/To/Directory/*
```

This then reports back the below for each file that you can then read in to capture the `LATEST` and/or "LATEST-1" versions:

```
version "/Path/To/Directory/file@@/main/5"
  created 2015-07-31T08:09:18+02:00 by #############
  "Automatically checkout by #############
  protected by rolemap: #############
  effective access for user #############
  Element Protection:
    User : #############
    Group: #############
    Other: #############
  element type: #############
  predecessor version: /main/4
  Labels:
    #############
  Attributes:
    Data_Status = #############
```

Comment: I have included your workaround (improving its output) in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands like [`cleartool diff`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diff.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-1-10) supports an option which refers to the "previous" version (`ct diff -pred`).
But the config spec itself only use label, branch or date.

As mentioned by the [OP Bendy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3972769/bendy), a [`cleartool describe /path/to/element`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-1-9) output does include the predecessor version.

Actually, [using `fmt_ccase`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-6-6&lang=en), a **`cleartool descr -fmt "%PSn"`** should display directly the `branch-pathname/version-number` of the predecessor version's version ID.

Comment: Thanks - that might still work as I could also use `ct get -to` generate a copy of the older files (I just need to then use them to process against the newer one in SAS). Do you know if there is a `-pred` for `ct get`? I can't find `-pred` mentioned for `diff` either

Comment: @Bendy no `--pred` for `get`: `cleartool get` uses the same version selector syntax.

Comment: @Bendy yes, no grep or output processing to do with that syntax.